# Aliasing in __init__.py

Tags: python

I am using python 3.10.7 and facing wierd issue.Kindly let me know if this is correct way to access things

**Case 1:**

My file structure is as follows:

```
calculator
 calcfunctions
  addition.py (def sum(a,b) in this file)
  subtraction.py
 __init__.py
main.py
```

The code in `__init__.py` is as follows:

```
list_languages = ["Rust","Java"]
import calcfunctions.addition
```

when i try to import module in console, it works perfectly fine as follows:

```
PS E:\practice\calculator> python
Python 3.10.7 (tags/v3.10.7:6cc6b13, Sep  5 2022, 14:08:36) [MSC v.1933 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import calcfunctions 
>>> calcfunctions.addition.sum(2,3) 
5
```

**Case 2:**

if i modify the code in `__init__.py` as follows

```
list_languages = ["Rust","Java"]
import calcfunctions.addition as summation
```

Now i try to import in repl, it gives error as follows:

```
PS E:\practice\calculator> python
Python 3.10.7 (tags/v3.10.7:6cc6b13, Sep  5 2022, 14:08:36) [MSC v.1933 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import calcfunctions
>>> calcfunctions.list_languages
['Rust', 'Java']
>>> calcfunctions.summation(2,3) 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
>>> summation(2,3)               
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'summation' is not defined
>>> summation.sum(2,3)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'summation' is not defined
```

What i could be doing wrong here?

Comment: Your `__init__.py` seems to be in `calculator`, but you never refer to that as a package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the `summation` in the top level of the `calcfunction` package to be a reference to the `sum` method defined in `calcfunction.addition`, you want  your import to be `from calcfunction.addition import sum as summation`. Since you're doing it in the package, you can use relative imports too, rather than naming `calcfunction` expicitly: `from .addition import sum as summation`.

If you want the main module (that you're running interactively) to have `summation` defined, you need to do a `from calcfunction import summation` call, rather than just importing `calcfunction` itself.

Answer (score 0):

It needs to be accessed in following manner:

```
>>> calcfunctions.summation.sum(2,3)
```